# I can't stop the thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have the following code and the thread is not stoping even if i close the form or exit the program with `System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();`.

My code:

```
bool shouldStop = false; 

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   backgroundThread = new Thread(
                      new ThreadStart(() =>
                      {    
                         for (int j = 0; j <= 1000; j++)
                         {
                            if (!shouldStop)
                            {
                               //do something
                            }

                            else
                            {
                               break;
                            }
                         }
                      }));
   backgroundThread.Start();
}

private void FormUpdateDB_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
   shouldStop = true;
}
```

Comment: Any chance that `// do something` is a really long task?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542061/how-do-i-stop-a-thread-when-my-winform-application-closes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So first off, exiting from the application simply ends that thread's message loop.  That won't *directly* tear down any other threads.

If you want the exiting of this application to end this other thread then all you need to do is make it a background thread.  (Set the `IsBackground` property to `true`.) and the thread will be torn down when no other non-background threads are running.

As for why the thread keeps going after you set `shouldStop` to `true`, you are not properly synchronizing access to the variable.  Because there is no memory barrier in place, the other thread is free to continue reading from a cached value of that variable, for as long as it wants to.  While you could synchronize access yourself, you shouldn't try to.  Instead, if it's important that this thread be a non-background thread (because it's doing something that cannot be stopped at some arbitrary point in time) then you should use a `CancellationToken` to cooperatively cancel another task.  The implementation of that type properly synchronizes access to the data between threads.

Comment: I make my thread backgroundThread, so how should I stop it? With CancellationToken?

Comment: @ChristosK. As I described in my answer, when there are no non-background threads running the entire process will be torn down, taking all of the background threads to the abyss with it.  A `CancellationToken` is only needed in the event that it's important for you to have a foreground thread.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
backgroundThread.IsBackground = true;
```

before the call to `Start()`