# Should I abort & join threads before exiting the main form?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

Well, should I? Assume that the child thread doesn't have to perform any sort of cleanup and can be terminated at any point.

```
    private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        MyThread.Abort();
        MyThread.Join();
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542061/how-do-i-stop-a-thread-when-my-winform-application-closes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the CLR already aborts it, assuming you've set its IsBackground to true.  You doing it yourself is slightly riskier, the CLR uses a bigger hammer to stop it.  Thread.Abort() can be ignored or cause the thread to fumble when it sees the ThreadAbortException, the CLR uses a rude abort that cannot be observed.