# "Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called..." when closing a window

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, invoke, invalidoperationexception

Ok there are lots of questions on this error, but I can't seem to find a solution for my issue. I have a thread that loads a control from the database during a long running operation. If I close my window before that thread finishes, it throws a  `Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.`, when doing the `Invoke`

I've modified the code to look like the following:

```
If Not Me.IsDisposed And Me.Created And Me.IsHandleCreated Then '
      Me.Invoke(New AddImageDelegate(AddressOf AddImage), item.PartNo, New Bitmap(item.ImagePath))
      Me.Invoke(New SetImageDelegate(AddressOf SetImage), I, item.PartNo)
End If
```

However it still hits the `Invoke` line and throws the error. When debugging stops on the exception, `IsDisposed` is true, `.Created` is false, and `.IsHandleCreated` is false. So checking those properties doesn't help.

So... how do i prevent it from running the invoke line in this situation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Winforms Threading: Closed Form Gets Invoked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3565551/c-sharp-winforms-threading-closed-form-gets-invoked)

Comment: @HansPassant, yes that seems to be the case. Always hard to find when there are so many similar problems that are not quite the same.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that Invoke had been called before your form was closed?

Rather than doing the If I would recommend not closing your form until you've managed to stop the second thread, its far safer.

Comment: The form is closed when the user closes the parent window, the thread belongs to a control nested somewhere in the form. Is there an easy way for the control to prevent the form from closing?

Comment: Without testing it I'm sure you can capture the onformclosing event ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.onformclosing.aspx) and set "e.Cancel = true".  This should cancel the close.  Or you could create a Property on the child form "IsClosable" and wait until your second thread sets it to true.  You could even block the parent thread in the Closing event until the second thread completes.