# How can I fix a NullReferenceException in System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripControlHost.SetVisibleCore?

Tags: c#, winforms

When setting control visibility I sometimes get this:

```
CRASH! Failed to refresh job control:
Exception:NullReferenceException
Message:Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source:     System.Windows.Forms
TargetSite: SetVisibleCore
StackTrace:    at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripControlHost.SetVisibleCore(Boolean visible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.set_Visible(Boolean value)
   at Cwc.WaterWorks.Console.frmMain.SetToolStripOptionalButtons()
   at Cwc.WaterWorks.Console.frmMain.UpdateToolStrip(ToolStripButton toolStripButton)
   at Cwc.WaterWorks.Console.frmMain.RefreshJobControl(Boolean fetch)
```

Called from:

```
private void SetToolStripOptionalButtons()
{

    NewJobButtonsVisibility(newJobStripButton.Checked);
    JobListButtonsVisibility(jobListStripButton.Checked);
    jumpToJob.Visible = !newJobStripButton.Checked;

    if (newJobStripButton.Checked)
    {
        JobCreateStatus(false);
            uxLockedToolStrip.Visible = false;
        HideJobControlButtons();
    }
    else if (jobListStripButton.Checked)
    {
        UpdateFilterStatus();
        HideJobControlButtons();
    }
        else if (controlStripButton.Checked)
    {
        ShowJobControlButtons();
        }

        findCustomerStripButton.Enabled = newJobStripButton.Checked && basis2ServiceLayer.Basis2Status.IsConnected==true;
    filterStripDropDown.Enabled = jobListStripButton.Checked;
}
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: What happened to the rest of the stack trace?  Was this written in VB.NET?

Comment: And post a snippet of SetToolStripOptionalButtons.

Comment: This is all the stack-trace I get as it is logged from the live system

Comment: I have a similar issue and my best guess is that this is getting called during/after the form and its control have been disposed. Is that a possible scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can repro this crash with a little test form:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        var strip = new ToolStrip();
        test = new ToolStripControlHost(new TextBox());
        strip.Items.Add(test);
        this.Controls.Add(strip);
    }
    protected override void OnMouseClick(MouseEventArgs e) {
        test.Dispose();
        test.Visible = true;
    }
    ToolStripItem test;
}
```

Click the window and kaboom:

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
  Message="Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
  Source="System.Windows.Forms"
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripControlHost.SetVisibleCore(Boolean visible)
       at WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.OnMouseClick(MouseEventArgs e) in C:\Users\hpass_000\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs:line 21
       ...
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at WindowsFormsApplication1.Program.Main() in C:\Users\hpass_000\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\Program.cs:line 15
```

So you are trying to update your Toolstrip item after it was disposed.  It isn't otherwise clear how your program got in a state like this.  Very high odds for a threading problem, a thread that keeps invoking even after the user closed the window.  The subject of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732361/17034).

You really ought to tackle the core problem but a Q&D fix that will probably solve your crash is:

```
private void SetToolStripOptionalButtons()
{
    if (this.Disposed) return;
    // etc...
}
```

Albeit that it may now well crash elsewhere.

Comment: How does this work when data binding is involved? Stated different, how do I check if the object has been disposed or not if I'm using data binding?

Comment: I have no clue how data binding could be involved in this.  Your stack trace is too truncated.  It it is not caused by a thread then something isn't getting disposed like it should when the form is closed.  Getting this crash to repro while you have a debugger attached sounds important.