# How to properly handle form closing when using background workers?

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

I am observing a strange bug in some of my code which I suspect is tied to the way closing a form and background workers interact.

Here is the code potentially at fault:

```
var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.DoWork += (sender, args) => {
        command();
    };
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, args) => {
        cleanup();
        if (args.Error != null)
            MessageBox.Show("...", "...", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
    };
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

This code is executed in a method in a form, when a button is pressed.
command() is slow, it may take a few seconds to run.

The user presses a button which executes the code above to be executed. Before it is done, the form is closed.

The problem is that calling cleanup() **sometimes** raises ObjectDisposedException. I say "sometimes", because this never happens on my computer. If the form is closed before command() is done, the handler I registered for RunWorkerCompleted is not executed. On another computer, the handler is called once out of hundred times. On a coworker's computer, it's almost always called. Apparently, the probability of execution of the handler rises with the age/slowness of the computer.

First question:

Is this the expected behaviour of BakgroundWorker? I would not expect it to know anything about the form, as there is nothing I can see that ties the form "this" with "worker".

Second question:

How should I go about fixing that problem?

Possible solutions I'm considering:

1. Test if (!this.IsDisposed) before calling cleanup(). Is that enough, or can the form be disposed while cleanup is being executed?
2. Wrap the call to cleanup() in a try {} catch (ObjectDisposedException). I don't like that kind of approach too much, as I may be catching exceptions that were raised due to some other unrelated bug in cleanup() or one of the methods it calls.
3. Register a handler for IsClosing and delay or cancel closing until the handler for RunWorker Completed has run.

Additional information that may be relevant: code from command() will cause updates to be done to GUI objects in "this". Such updates are performed via calls to this F# function:

```
/// Run a delegate on a ISynchronizeInvoke (typically a Windows.Form).
let runOnInvoker (notification_receiver : ISynchronizeInvoke) excHandler (dlg : Delegate) args =
    try
        let args : System.Object[] = args |> Seq.cast |> Array.ofSeq
        notification_receiver.Invoke (dlg, args) |> ignore
    with
        | :? System.InvalidOperationException as op ->
            excHandler(op)
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not one of the GUI updates that throws?

Comment: You say "I would not expect it to know anything about the form, as there is nothing I can see that ties the form "this" with "worker"." But are `command` and `cleanup` perhaps methods of the form?

Comment: CodeInChaos: Anything that's thrown from command() should cause RunWorkerCompleted to be raised with the exception in args.Error. That's not happening here.

Comment: Jordi: command and cleanup are lambdas created within methods of the form.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to stop BackgroundWorker on Form's Closing event?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731384/how-to-stop-backgroundworker-on-forms-closing-event)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exceptions you mentioned do not have any connection to `BackgroundWorker`, other than the fact that one thread (the worker) tries to access controls which have been disposed by another thread (the UI).

The solution I would use is to attach an event handler to the `Form.FormClosed` event to set a flag that tells you the UI has been torn down. Then, then `RunWorkerCompleted` handle will check to see if the UI has been torn down before trying to do anything with the form.

While this approach will probably work more reliably than checking `IsDisposed` if you are not disposing the form explicitly, it does not provide a 100% guarantee that the form will not be closed and/or disposed just after the cleanup code has checked the flag and found that it is still there. This is the race condition you yourself mention.

To eliminate this race condition, you will need to synchronize, for example like this:

```
// set this to new object() in the constructor
public object CloseMonitor { get; private set; }

public bool HasBeenClosed { get; private set; }

private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e) {
    lock (this.CloseMonitor) {
        this.HasBeenClosed = true;
        // other code
    }
}
```

and for the worker:

```
worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, args) => {
    lock (form.CloseMonitor) {
        if (form.HasBeenClosed) {
            // maybe special code for this case
        }
        else {
            cleanup();
            // and other code
        }
    }
};
```

The `Form.FormClosing` event will also work fine for this purpose, you can use whichever of the two is more convenient if it makes a difference.

Note that, the way this code is written, both event handlers will be scheduled for execution on the UI thread (this is because WinForms components use a single-threaded apartment model) so you would actually not be affected by a race condition. However, if you decide to spawn more threads in the future you might expose the race condition unless you do use locking. In practice I have seen this happen quite often, so I suggest synchronizing anyway to be future-proof. Performance will not be affected as the sync only happens once.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on using FormClosed and locking. I have some remarks: 1. Shouldn't I be using FormClosing instead? I would expect that the handler for FormClosed could be executed **after** the form is closed (and disposed). 2. Using FormClosed or FormClosing does not protect against other ways of disposing the form. I'm not disposing it explicitly, but maybe there are other reasons my form could be disposed I don't know of?

Comment: Additional comment: If we forget about disposal and focus on closing, do I need the lock? The handlers for FormClosing and RunWorkerCompleted both execute on the same thread, right?

Comment: The form obviously should not be disposed while it is visible, if that happens for any reason it's a bug in your code (the runtime won't do it behind your back). For the other questions, I expanded the answer a bit.

Comment: The form *does* get disposed while it is visible.  Happens automatically when the user closes it or the app terminates.  The comment about locking is accurate too.

Comment: Jon: As a response to my first question (using FormClosing instead of FormClosed), you wrote "The Form.FormClosing event will also work fine for this purpose". I could be wrong, but I am under the impression that using FormClosed is unsafe. The sequence is: user clicks X -> FormClosing raised -> FormClosing handler called -> unless cancelled, the form is closed and FormClosed raised -> FormClosed handler called. Isn't it possible for the handler of RunWorkerCompleted to slip in between "form is closed" and "FormClosed handler called"?

Comment: It is, but the safe/unsafe status depends on what exactly you are doing inside `cleanup`. I just mentioned the two events because either one might work "better" for your specific scenario. Use that one. :)