# C# Can't close form created by Background Worker

Tags: c#, multithreading, forms, backgroundworker

My Backgroundworker loads a new "pop-up" form, but how do I terminate background worker and the newly created form?

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BussyForm bussyForm = new BussyForm();
    bussyForm.ShowDialog();
}
```

This has no effect:

```
backgroundWorker1.Dispose();
backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
backgroundWorker1 = null;
```

Comment: Info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387527/how-to-properly-handle-form-closing-when-using-background-workers) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16770337/closing-the-form-when-backgroundworker-stops-working).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be showing a form from a non-UI thread.  You should only have one UI thread, and it, and only it, should access all of your user interface controls.  Your non-UI threads shouldn't access UI elements at all.

You should be showing the given busy popup from the UI thread instead.

Requesting cancellation from the `BackgroundWorker`, or disposing of it, won't close the form, or force the thread to stop executing, which is why your form stays open.

Instead just show your popup from the UI thread when you start the background worker, and have the BGW's completed event call `Close` on the form:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    BusyForm busyForm = new BusyForm();

    BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (_, e) => { busyForm.Close(); };
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();

    busyForm.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: Ok.. I understand. I need to rethink my design. Thanks for the code!

Answer (score 0):

`CancelAsync` doesn't actually abort your thread or anything like that. It sends a message to the worker thread that work should be cancelled via `BackgroundWorker.CancellationPending`. Your DoWork delegate that is being ran in the background must periodically check this property and handle the cancellation itself.

You call `bussyForm.ShowDialog();` so you need to close this form manually.

Comment: Did you try backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending?

Comment: Problem was i had two UI threads, so Im back to one, and now it works