# Trying to avoid exceptions when calling back to the UI thread

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, invalidoperationexception

I have a type of control that holds a GridView and some utility buttons. The control is used everywhere in my application. It is populated asynchronously, through delegates:

```
    protected virtual void PopulateGridView()
    {
        if (isPopulating) return;

        //a delegate given to the control by its parent form
        if (GetterMethod != null)
        {
            isPopulating = true;
            /*unimportant UI fluff here*/

            //some controls are fast enough to not have to mess with threading
            if(PopulateSynchronously) 
            {
                PopulateWithGetterMethod();
                InitializeGridView();
            }
            else //most aren't
            {
                Action asyncMethod = PopulateWithGetterMethod;
                asyncMethod.BeginInvoke(
                   ar => Invoke((MethodInvoker)InitializeGridView)), null);
            }
        }
    }

    private void PopulateWithGetterMethod()
    {
        //a list of whetever the control is displaying;
        //the control ancestor and this collection are generic.
        RetrievedInformation = GetterMethod();
    }

    protected virtual void InitializeGridView()
    {
        //use RetrievedInformation to repopulate the GridView;
        //implementation not important, except it touches UI elements,
        //so it needs to be called from the worker thread using Invoke.
    }
```

On long-running queries, sometimes the user would get impatient and close the window. Or, the user would serendipitously close a window when one of the controls was auto-refreshing based on a Timer. When that happened, and the query DID finish, the Invoke call in the callback delegate would fail with an InvalidOperationException because the control didn't have a window handle.

To fix this, I attempted to use the built-in IsHandleCreated property:

```
    ...
            else
            {
                Action asyncMethod = PopulateWithGetterMethod;
                asyncMethod.BeginInvoke(
                   ar => { if(IsHandleCreated)
                              Invoke((MethodInvoker)InitializeGridView)); 
                         }, null);
            }
```

However, the exception still happens, just not as often. I managed to reproduce it, and found that the Invoke call still happened, even though the watch on IsHandleCreated showed false. My guess is that the thread was pre-empted between the check and the Invoke call, like you'd see with checking an event delegate for null before raising it.

I still have options, I think, but I'm wondering what the best is:

- Check not only IsHandleCreated, but Disposing, to make sure the control really is alive and well, and not JUST about to be destroyed.
- Perform a Thread.Yield() before making the check, to allow the OS a chance to do any window management before checking for the handle.
- Wrap the Invoke call in a try/catch that suppresses any InvalidOperationExceptions, or at least ones reporting the lack of a window handle. Honestly, in this case, I don't care that the GridView can't be updated; the user closed the window, so obviously they don't care. Let the thread die quietly, without taking down the whole app.

The third option seems like a cop-out; there has to be a cleaner way to handle it. But, I'm not sure that either of the other two will be a 100% fix.

**EDIT**: Checking Disposing and IsDisposed didn't work either; I got an exception thrown out from within an if block with the condition "IsHandleCreated && !Disposing && !IsDisposed", in which the first and last nodes were false when watched. Currently I'm trapping all exceptions with the message "Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.", which is what I'd hoped not to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there's a 100% clean way to do this: terminate the thread before you allow the form to close.  Anything else is a band-aid over a nasty cut, checking if the form is still alive is an inevitable race condition that you cannot solve.  You can only minimize the odds that the form is gonzo when you call Invoke(), you can't eliminate them.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731384/how-to-stop-backgroundworker-on-forms-closing-event/1732361#1732361) for the pattern.

Comment: Elegant, and I can probably figure out something that'll work along these lines. However, my situation isn't that simple; the asynchronous code is encapsulated down in a UserControl, not the Form. There can be several of these on one window, so the solution would have to make sure ALL threads had executed. Lastly, the #1 cause of the bug is users either getting fed up or realizing they'd made a mistake and clicking the X; to keep the window around after the user wants it gone is not an ideal user experience. None of this is insurmountable.

Comment: We had the same problem Keith is describing and swallowed the exception when we were showing an error message box from the background thread.  There's really no way to, without swallowing an exception, solve this problem.  In addition to that, the order in which Windows Handles are disposed is not necessarily the order in which they are created so you can't rely on logical flows to get out of this scenario.  Even in your example, you're racing on mCompleted and mClosePending.

Comment: No, these variables are only ever accessed on the UI thread.  That cannot race.

Comment: I gave Hans the check because his answer is "right" from a code design perspective; you usually want to avoid swallowing exceptions, because you may end up swallowing an exception that happened in a different circumstance you might want to know about. Or, the code could break again if the exception type or message changes. HOWEVER, it turned out that implementing Hans' solution required a LOT more work. I had to expose the event, then attach a handler to ALL of these controls, wherever they were, then resolve quirky behavior with other closing tasks like remembering window size/position.

Comment: So, Nate, while Hans' answer is "doing it right", there's a lot to say for "doing it light" as well, and if I didn't have as much time as I do to resolve this problem I would have gone with the try/catch and moved on.

Comment: Agreed Keith, this thread is making me want to go back and refactor some code.  And Hans, I forgot that the BGW complete thread returns to the main thread. My apologies.

Answer (score 1):

Disposing is your best bet; however, we have this same problem every once in awhile and sometimes the Disposing call returns false but by the time we try to use the control it's disposed, even if it's 3 lines later.

In these cases, we've found it best to catch a specific exception and also verify the exception text contains what we're looking for.  If it's an exception and it's a known exception, then swallowing it isn't a terrible idea.  The thing is to make sure you're only swallowing the specific exception you're looking for.