# How to check a forms background work from another form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, multithreading

I have 2 winforms, one (call it Form1) contains a background worker, and that form opens a second form (Form2).  Form1 starts a background worker, and while its working opens Form2 so the user can do something else.  When the user is done on Form2 and clicks submit, I want to check if Form1's background worker is done and if it isn't pop a message asking the user to wait a minute, else allow the Form2 submit.

How can I check the status of Form1's background worker from Form2?  I looked at this post [Check to see if a thread in another form is still running](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7001256/456532) , but my situation is different and I'm not sure how to adapt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [BackgroundWorker.IsBusy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.isbusy.aspx) property.

**Edit**

There are various options for making this information available to the second form.

- You could pass the BackgroundWorker to Form2 on creation. Form2 can then check the `IsBusy` property.
- You could create a public property `IsRunningBackgroundWork` on Form1, and give Form2 a reference to Form1. The getter for this property would check `BackgroundWorker.IsBusy`.
- You could create a public property `CanSubmit` on Form2, and set it from Form1 when the BackgroundWorker completes.

  `bgw.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, e) => form2.CanSubmit = true;`

Alternatively (and I think this is best) you could put the submission code in Form1, and just use Form2 as a dialog. Then Form2 doesn't need to know anything about Form1. Form1 opens Form2 modally, and when Form2 closes, Form1 checks if the worker is finished, and acts accordingly.

Comment: -Yes, but I can't "see" the background worker from the other form.

Comment: @MAW: added some suggestions to my answer.

Comment: -Used CanSubmit variable on Form2 set from background worker's completed method.  Used for simplicity and ease.

Answer (score 0):

The situation is *almost* similiar to that one provided in your question.
You can do something like this:

```
public class Form1 
{
   public bool IsBackgroundWorkerStillRunning {get {....};}
}


public class Form2 
{
    Form1 form1 = null;
    public Form2(Form1 frm1)
    {
      form1 = frm1;
    }

     private void OnSubmit(...)
     {
         if(form1.IsBackgroundWorkerStillRunning )
              //wait 
         else
              //proceed
     }
}
```

one the Form1 have a property which checks for background worker state

Comment: -Did not work because I don't have visibility on Form1 from Form2.

Comment: @MAW74656: in Form2 you have form1  which is actually intialized to Form1 caller object.