# Preventing Form closure from freezing Invoke calls

Tags: c#, winforms

In my application I've created a thread which draws on a `Bitmap` object, and when it is done drawing it calls `form.Invoke(form.Refresh)` which draws the bitmap to the main form. (`form` being a reference to the main form of my application.)

**The Problem**: I've noticed that if I close the form while the other thread is waiting for the callback message from UI thread (because of the `Invoke` call) - the thread will wait indefinitely(?) and will essentially get stuck, preventing the application from closing.

Using `BeginInvoke` doesn't make sense in my program, because the time it takes to refresh the form has to be accounted for in the work of the thread.

**Q:** What would be the best way to prevent this from happening?

**Edit:** I've read in some places that its a bad idea, but it seems to me that the only way to deal with this is to call `Thread.Abort()`. I can't close the thread by using a flag or something similar, since its just stuck at the `Invoke` call.

**Edit 2:** To make it clear, what I'm looking for is a way to tell the worker thread that it should stop waiting for the `Invoke` callback and continue working.

Comment: This normally aborts the Invoke() call with an ObjectDisposedException, raised right after the form is disposed.  But it is an unsolvable threading race, the thread might call Invoke() while the form is busy disposing.  That's bad.  Don't allow the form to close until the thread stops running.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to stop BackgroundWorker on Form's Closing event?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731384/how-to-stop-backgroundworker-on-forms-closing-event)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best answer is of course to use BeginInvoke. If you need the thread to wait until the UI thread has processed the result, then you'll have to add another synchronization method to the process.

An AutoResetEvent would work as a gate, something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class MainForm : Form
{
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        new Thread(ProcessBitmap) { IsBackground = true }.Start(null);
        base.OnLoad(e);
    }

    void DoneProcessingBitmap(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("Done Processing Bitmap");
        uiDoneEvent.Set();
    }

    AutoResetEvent uiDoneEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    volatile bool terminate = false;

    void ProcessBitmap(object state)
    {
        while (!terminate)
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)state;
            Trace.WriteLine("Processing Bitmap");
            Thread.Sleep(5000); // simulate processing
            BeginInvoke(new Action<Bitmap>(DoneProcessingBitmap), bitmap);
            Trace.WriteLine("Waiting");
            uiDoneEvent.WaitOne();
        }
    }

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new MainForm());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the form still exists before calling `Invoke`.  Something like...

```
if (form != null && !form.Disposed)
    form.Invoke(form.Refresh());
```

Comment: The problem is, the `Refresh` method can be quite time consuming and this problem appears when the form closes after `Invoke` has been called but before the callback message from the UI Thread has been received - thus making the worker thread wait for a message that will never come. If I call invoke on a disposed form it will simply throw an exception.