# When closing the application while its working sometimes im getting exception for not releasing an object why?

Tags: c#

ObjectDisposedException was caught.

Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'Form1'.

Thats when the backgorundworker is working and i click the X red X on the right top corner to close the application when its in the middle of the work sometimes its throwing this exception.

```
System.ObjectDisposedException was caught
  Message=Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'Form1'.
  Source=System.Windows.Forms
  ObjectName=Form1
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.MarshaledInvoke(Control caller, Delegate method, Object[] args, Boolean synchronous)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(Delegate method, Object[] args)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(Delegate method)
       at GatherLinks.Form1.test(String url, Int32 levels, DoWorkEventArgs eve) in D:\C-Sharp\GatherLinks\GatherLinks\GatherLinks\Form1.cs:line 126
  InnerException:
```

Line 126 in this case is:

```
this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { Texts(richTextBox1, " Done " + Environment.NewLine, Color.Red); }));
```

What should i do to fix/repair this exception and what objects or variables should i release/close when exiting the application ?

The test function:

```
private List<string> test(string url, int levels,DoWorkEventArgs eve)
        {
            levels = levelsToCrawl;
            HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
            List<string> webSites;
            List<string> csFiles = new List<string>();

            csFiles.Add("temp string to know that something is happening in level = " + levels.ToString());
            csFiles.Add("current site name in this level is : " + url);

            try
            {
                this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { Texts(richTextBox1, "Loading The Url:   " + url + "..." , Color.Red); }));
                HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = GetHtmlDoc(url, reqOptions, null);
                if (timeOut == true)
                {
                    this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { Texts(richTextBox1, " There Was A TimeOut" + Environment.NewLine , Color.Red); }));
                    timeOut = false;
                    return csFiles;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { Texts(richTextBox1, " Done " + Environment.NewLine, Color.Red); }));
                }
                currentCrawlingSite.Add(url);
                webSites = getLinks(doc);
                removeDupes(webSites);
                removeDuplicates(webSites, currentCrawlingSite);
                removeDuplicates(webSites, sitesToCrawl);
                if (removeExt == true)
                {
                    removeExternals(webSites);
                }
                if (downLoadImages == true)
                {
                    retrieveImages(url);                 }

                if (levels > 0)
                    sitesToCrawl.AddRange(webSites
                this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { label7.Text = sitesToCrawl.Count.ToString(); }));
                this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { label3.Text = currentCrawlingSite.Count().ToString(); }));



                if (levels == 0)
                {
                    return csFiles;
                }
                else
                {


                    for (int i = 0; i < webSites.Count(); i++)//&& i < 20; i++)                     {
                        int mx = Math.Min(webSites.Count(), 20); 


                            string t = webSites[i];
                            if ((t.StartsWith("http://") == true) || (t.StartsWith("https://") == true)) 
                            {

                                csFiles.AddRange(test(t, levels - 1, eve));
                            }

                    }
                    return csFiles;
                }



            }
            catch
            {
                return csFiles;
            }

        }
```

And the backgroundworker DoWork and ProgressReport events:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {

                this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { label2.Text = "Website To Crawl: "; }));
                this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { label4.Text = mainUrl; }));
                test(mainUrl, levelsToCrawl, e);


        }

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {


        }
```

Comment: Without context on the cause of that code being fired, it's almost certainly because the Form, `Form1` has been Disposed, and then your event is invoked.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to stop BackgroundWorker on Form's Closing event?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731384/how-to-stop-backgroundworker-on-forms-closing-event)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your form is being disposed, and then your BackgroundWorker is trying to update a control which belonged to the disposed form.

You could handle your form's `FormClosing` event and stop the worker, or wait for it to complete.

Alternatively, your BackgroundWorker could check the form's `IsDisposed` property before attempting to write out the status.

But really, you should be using [`ReportProgress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3zbdb1t.aspx), rather than `Invoke` - which would avoid the problem as well.

Comment: How do i do it with the reportprogress ? The test function is function that working all the time calling it self. In the backgroundworker DoWork event im calling this test function onmce first time . Then the function test is calling it self all the time. In the backgroundworker ReportProgress event im not doing anything for now. So i need to use somehow to report from the test function and do something in the reportprogress event. How should i do it ?