# windows forms - calling Control.Invoke is giving error suggesting the control hasn't been loaded

Tags: winforms, multithreading, events, controls

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to stop BackgroundWorker on Form's Closing event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731384/how-to-stop-backgroundworker-on-forms-closing-event)

I have some code in a Windows Form a bit like this:

```
button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Widget myWidget = new Widget(...bunch of constructor parameters...);
  myWidget.Property1 = "blah"; // other properties get set here too...
  myWidget.InterestingThingHappened += InterestingThingHappened;

  Parallel.Invoke(myWidget.RunInterestingLongRunningProcess());
}

private void InterestingThingHappened(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  myLabel.Invoke(new Action(() => myLabel.Text = "An interesting thing happened!"))
}
```

When I run it, the application just freezes until I kill it in Task Manager. Then I see an Exception saying 'Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.' `button1_Click` is clearly a control event handler, so the form is fully created before this code runs. I have absolutely no idea what this means. Can anyone help?

Comment: While Googling this problem, I would never have recognised the question you posted as being the same as mine. It still don't see that it is...

Comment: This is in no sense a duplicate of the linked question. My code doesn't use BackgroundWorker. I'm not trying to close a form. I wonder if there's a way to appeal this?

Answer (score 0):

Using `BeginInvoke()` rather than `Invoke()` fixed the problem completely. The UI updated in real time. Why? Who knows?

Comment: I've no clue why your app didn't work and wouldn't dare post an answer but, as a general rule, always use asynchronous inter-thread comms if at all possible.  The deadlock-potential of synchronous comms is just too high.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I'm afraid I don't know what asynchronous or synchronous inter-thread comms are. Can you be more specific?