# "Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created" only occurs the second time form opens

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, delegates

The application I am developing is a plugin to an existing application and the first time running the plugin everything works great. However when I open the plugin a second time I get the error:

*InvalidOperationException was unhandled - Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.*

I understand race conditions and from everything I've read, this error occurs when trying to access a form element before `HandleCreated` is true, but I cannot figure out why this is happening only the second time I open the plugin.

Here is the plugin code. The error occurs when calling `SetProgressBar()`:

```
    private MainForm mainForm;

    public void StartPlugin()
    {
        mainForm  = new MainForm (this);
        mainForm .ShowDialog();
    }

    public bool GetJoinEnabled()
    {
        mainForm.SetProgressBar(3);
    }
```

Here's my main form:

```
    private Thread m_JoinThread;
    private JoinPlugin m_Join;

    public MainForm(JoinPlugin zig)
    {
        m_Join = zig;
        InitializeComponent();
        m_JoinThread= new Thread(new ThreadStart(GetJoinData));
        m_JoinThread.Start();
    }

    private void GetJoinData()
    {
       //Get enable join data
        bool result = m_Join.GetJoinEnabled();
    }

    public void SetProgressBar(int value)
    {
        SetProgressCallback del = new SetProgressCallback(SetProgressBarControl);
        this.Invoke(del, value);
    }

    private void SetProgressBarControl(int value)
    {
        progressBar.Value = value;
    }
```

Comment: Does it happen if you add `mainForm.Dispose();` after `mainForm.ShowDialog();`?

Comment: it's strange that your `MainForm` becomes `ZigbeeJoinForm` in definition code? Unless your `MainForm` inherits `ZigbeeJoinForm`.

Comment: `delegate` is a keyword which can't be used for variable name but this code line of yours is an exception? `SetProgressCallback delegate = new SetProgressCallback(SetProgressBarControl);`

Comment: I think this code would fail right at the first time running, I can understand why it would fail but it's strange that you said it's OK for the first time running.

Comment: @KingKing the delegate variable and ZigbeeJoinForm were mistakes when editing my question. I changed some of the naming around to make it easier to understand

Comment: There's a clear race condition in the code, you start the thread too early.  Not stopping the thread *before* the window is closed is also a serious problem.

Comment: @HansPassant Is there a proper way to stop a thread before the window is closed?

Comment: @keyboardP Yes it still happens. Joes answer below seems to be working.

Comment: It is covered in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731384/how-to-stop-backgroundworker-on-forms-closing-event/1732361#1732361)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing a little, but i ran into the same issue some time ago.

You are starting a thread in the forms constructor:

```
m_JoinThread.Start();
```

This starts the thread immediatedly and call `Invoke` somewhere. At this time, the form is not initilized completely.
Move the code to the `Load` event:

```
public ZigbeeJoinForm_Load()
{
    m_JoinThread= new Thread(new ThreadStart(GetJoinData));
    m_JoinThread.Start();
}
```

This ensures that the form is completely initialized and calling `Invoke` is safe then.