# VB.NET: How to control the Form that is displayed when the program starts from Sub Main

Tags: vb.net, winforms, program-entry-point

VB.NET 2012
My Startup Object is set to (Sub Main). The app needs to collect a few different sets of data before the primary form is loaded

This article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235406(v=vs.110).aspx mentions

> In Main, you can determine which form is to be loaded first when the program starts

**But it never explains how to show the form**

If I use ShowDialog the application terminates when mainView’s Visible property is set to False or when mainView is Hidden

```
Module Module1
    Public mainView As New Form1
    Public Sub Main()
        ' initialization code
        mainView.ShowDialog() ' this works until I need to hide mainView, ShowDialog returns and the app terminates
    End Sub
End Module
```

If I use Show the application immediately falls out of Sub Main and terminates

```
Module Module1
    Public mainView As New Form1
    Public Sub Main()
        ' initialization code
        mainView.Show() ' this doesn't work at all, the app terminates as soon as Main is executed
    End Sub
End Module
```

- The primary form needs to exist the entire time the app is running.
- I need sections of code to run before the primary form is displayed.
- I need to be able to hide the primary at times and show it at others.

What is the best approach to achieve these requirements?

Comment: You are missing a messaging loop. Try `Application.Run(New Form1)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to extend splash screen into form shown event?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25553657/is-there-a-way-to-extend-splash-screen-into-form-shown-event)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work perfectly. I had read about the messaging loop but it didn’t seem to work until I tried it like below, thanks LarsTech

```
Module Module1
    Public mainView As Form1
    Public Sub Main()
        ' initialization code
        ''...
        Application.EnableVisualStyles()
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(False)
        mainView = New Form1
        Application.Run(mainView) ' I can reference 'mainView' from anywhere in my app, toggle its Visible  property etc.
    End Sub
End Module
```