# Is Me.IsHandleCreated a reliable indicator to determine whether the form has been closed?

Tags: vb.net, formclosing

I have found that it seems to be, but i do not understand the internal workings of this property to know for sure. When the user closes the form, this property seems to reliably return False.

I use this when i have background workers running, and i check this property in the completed event before doing any further processing.

Comment: Not exactly, it is also False when the window wasn't yet created.  You only *really* care about IsDisposed.  Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731384/how-to-stop-backgroundworker-on-forms-closing-event/1732361#1732361)

Comment: Hans, background processes in my application are only ever kicked off as a result of a user clicking a button so there would be no way that i would ever be checking this property before the form was created. If i try and invoke methods on my form from a background worker and the form is closed (but not yet disposed) is "Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.". Checking ishandlecreated works perfectly in that situation where me.isdisposed does not

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use that. Agreeing with Hans Passant, I would use Me.IsDisposed because that will check to make sure that it was open and then shut down and disposed the memory.

Comment: The problem with Me.IsDisposed is that it returns true after the form is closed. It doesnt get disposed instantly after, only after garbage collection right?

Comment: "When this property returns true, the control is disposed of and can no longer be referenced as a valid Windows control. Even though the instance of a control is disposed of, it is still maintained in memory until it is removed from memory through garbage collection." -MSDN