# How to safely close a main form when there are child threads opening message boxes

Tags: c#

In my C# code there is a Main window which starts multiple threads.Some of these thread cause message boxes to show.When i close the main window I need all the threads i started to be aborted safely.I tried doing it by adding the threads to a list and then aborting them.But everytime ThreadAbort exception is thrown.
Please suggest me a way to do this

Comment: Show the code you used when adding them to a list

Comment: Displaying message boxes from a thread solves one problem but creates three new ones.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to stop BackgroundWorker on Form's Closing event?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731384/how-to-stop-backgroundworker-on-forms-closing-event)

Comment: Have you considered the design of your application?  It sounds like you're having to resort to this because you feel you do not know how to do this in a safe/logical way.

Comment: @Moo-Juice I am actually using REST messages for communication in the thread.But sometimes the response takes too much time to receive.This keeps the thread alive for longer duration.Is there a way a better way to wait for the REST response?

Comment: @ShaijuJanardhanan, have a look at doing it asynchronously so that your main UI thread isn't blocked.

Answer (score 2):

The very purpose of `Thread.Abort` *is* raising a `ThreadAbortException`. This kills the thread.

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.abort%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> **Thread.Abort Method**
>
> Raises a ThreadAbortException in the thread on which it is invoked, to begin the process of terminating the thread. Calling this method usually terminates the thread.

Using `Thread.Abort` will not terminate the thread in a clean way. The usual safe solution for stopping a thread is creating a `volatile bool` stop flag on that thread, which your thread checks from time to time to know whether it should stop.

Comment: is there any other way to do it?

Comment: In a graceful way? I don't know of any.