# BackgroundWorker for Each Form C++(CLR Project)

Tags: c++, .net, opencv, clr

I am working on C++(CLR Project for OpenCV better GUI). I have two forms in CLR Project: parentForm and childForm. **Both use BackgroundWorker**.

parentForm is reading frames from all connected camera device(s) and displaying them in pictureBox(s). It create childForm on pictureBox click_event.
childForm is performing background-Subtraction on selected camera device and displaying result in pictureBox.

**Problem is**: Since both forms using their own backgroundWorker. If i run parentForm, and close it: no Problem. But if I run ParentForm, load ChildForm from it(two backgroundWorker in this case), it throws an Exception (`System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException`)

I read on StackOverflow that if one form closed, all running backgroundWorker stops, i.e. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9632856/5051106). Please help or give me any idea how to handle BackgroundWorker for each multiple Form!