# Wait for BackgroundWorker finish, if running, at FormClosing time

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker, wait, autoresetevent

How can I wait for [`BackgroundWorker`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx) to finish, if running, when the user request to close application? I'd like to wait to this [`BackgroundWorker`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx) finish then exit application. I tried with [`AutoResetEvent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx) but a call to [`WaitOne()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58195swd(v=vs.110).aspx) at FormClosing time seems to block the entire UI and doesn't fire RunWorkerCompleted event where [`Set()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle.set(v=vs.110).aspx) is called. 
How can I accomplish this?

I'm looking for an alternative/proper way for this:

```
bool done = false;
        private void my_backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            resetEvent.Set();
            done = true;
        }

        private void myForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (notify_backgroundWorker.IsBusy)
            {
                while(!done)
                {
                    Application.DoEvents();
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                }
                //resetEvent.WaitOne();
            }
        }
```

Comment: See [How to stop BackgroundWorker on Form's Closing event?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1731384/719186)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to make it so complex, just have a class level variable

```
bool quitRequestedWhileWorkerBusy=false;
```

If the user tried to close the form, in the form closing event check if the worker isbusy, cancel the event and set `quitRequestedWhileWorkerBusy=true`

In your worker completed event, `if(quitRequestedWhileWorkerBusy) this.Close();`

Answer (score 0):

Another way is based on OP's sample code, but simplified:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    // Stop the background worker thread (if running) to avoid race hazard.
    if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();

        // Wait for the background worker thread to actually finish.
        while (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }
}
```