# Invoke Property

Tags: c#, multithreading, invoke

I have written a program in a synchronous model that I now want to add threading to for long tasks, I have several properties that automate the retrieval of certain information like:

```
private int tabIdx { get { return tabs.SelectedIndex; } }

private string tabName { get { return tabs.SelectedTab.Text; } }

public TabControls TabControls { get { return (TabControls)tabs.TabPages[tabIdx].Controls[string.Format("tab_{0}_controls", tabIdx)]; } }
internal TabControls getTabControls(string name)
{
    int desiredIdx = tabs.TabPages.IndexOfKey(name);
    return (TabControls)tabs.TabPages[desiredIdx].Controls[string.Format("tab_{0}_controls", desiredIdx)];
}

public Core rCore { get { return rdbCores[tabIdx]; } }
```

Obviously if I try to access these properties from inside `Task.Run(())` or likewise I'm going to get a cross-thread exception.

So my question is:

Is it possible to Invoke these properties with an method similar too:

```
private void invokeIfRequired(ISynchronizeInvoke obj, MethodInvoker action)
{
    if (obj.InvokeRequired) { obj.Invoke(action, new object[0]); }
    else { action(); }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45961869/17034

Answer (score 0):

In general, I use the following to invoke Properties from different Tasks. I can't follow your code, wehre you want to invoke, so you have to adjust the code to you application needs:

```
button1.Invoke(new Action(()=>button1.Visible = true;))
```